# Sorting datatable columns

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables, columnsorting

I have datatable column which has negative as well as positive numbers,
I need to sort them in ascending order i.e (negative values first) followed by positive values -

Here is my sort method -

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
"num-html-pre": function ( a ) {
   // var x = String(a).replace(/(?!^-)[^0-9.]/g, "");
    return parseFloat( a );
},

"num-html-asc": function ( a, b ) {
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
},

"num-html-desc": function ( a, b ) {
    return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
}
});
```

I just dont understand what is wrong here.

Comment: I hope, you have used `$('table').dataTable({
      "aoColumns": [{
        "sType": "num-html"
      }],` while initialize datatable

Comment: Yes I have included -  "aoColumns": [{ 'sClass': 'right' , "sType": 'num-html'}],